# Capture and check bteq return code in Unix

Tags: unix, teradata, return-code

I'm developing a script which in turn invokes several other scripts (.ksh). And basically when one of them fail they shouldn't proceed to the next one. So I tried checking for the return code in one script that involves `bteq` (Basic Teradata Query) session. Please find below the scenario:

```
 bteq <<EOF!
 .run file ${TGTRUNFILEN} ;
 .maxerror 1;
 .set width 245;
 ...
 ...
 sel * from table ;
 .if ACTIVITYCOUNT <> 0 then .GOTO QUIT
 .os mail command "error msg"
 exit 1;
 .LABEL QUIT
 .quit;
EOF!
echo $rcode
rcode=$?    
if [[ $rcode != 0 ]]
     then
         echo "$0: Insufficient Perm Space : username " >&2
         exit 4
fi
```

Here,the script fails and I can see the log saying failed with return code 1, but why isn't the text "$0:Insufficient Perm Space : Username" displayed. I think it exits the entire script, but I need this fixed somehow.
Can someone kindly help me on this?

Comment: What happens when you `echo $rcode` before the `if` test: is the value 0?  Does `bteq` actually exit with a non-zero status on demand?

Comment: Even if give  `echo $rcode` ,nothing happens.Im unable to see anything after the `exit` or `quit` statement.Im totally clueless at the moment.

Comment: Since you truncated the top of the script, we can't see the here-document line.  Please add that.  It should contain something like: `bteq <<'EOF!'` (probably with some extra arguments to `bteq`, which would conventionally be placed before the here-document specification).  Don't show us any actual passwords, and be cautious about user names and host names (`example.com` is useful here). However, if you made a mistake, you might not get told about it (funnier things have been known).  If you omitted the `!`, or if the `EOF!` line also has a trailing blank on it, you have problems.

Comment: Thanks Jon.But I checked,no trailing spaces.I've added the here-document line above.I don't see anything amiss here.Still not clear what am i missing.

Comment: There's a back-quote at the top before `bteq` and a single quote at the bottom after `fi`; I assume these are not really present in your real script because between them they make your script syntactically incorrect.  If they were both back-quotes, it would mean something — but probably not what you want.

Comment: Please ignore those backquotes.This is the real script running in our prod.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Thanks a ton for responding.I found a way to overcome this.I just added 'set' command like this.

```
 set +e
 bteq <<EOF!
 ...
 ...
 EOF!
 rcode=$?
 set -e
```

Works fine for me.

Cheers